# Why Nationalism and Patriotism seem like it swap meaning?

Tags: etymology, history

When I try to distinguish these two words I found many people link something like intolerance and illogical with Nationalism while Patriotism seem more progressive. But from etymology the word Patriot felt more militaristic and require obedient than Nation

What happen to these words and why we have these mismatch meaning?

Comment: Words of this nature are "adopted" by political movements and this tends to distort their meaning.

Answer (score 1):

Webster's 1913 Dictionary has this as one of its definitions for [nationalism](https://www.webster-dictionary.org/definition/nationalism):

> 6. The policy of advocating the interests of one's own country exclusively, regardless of effects of a country's actions on other countries.

This sense of the word carries a more negative connotation than patriotism. Often in political discourse, the word *nationalism* is used in this negative sense, while people tend to use *patriotism* to talk about the more positive aspects of dedication to one's country.